# How to validate file size and extension in FastAPI?

Tags: fastapi

The problem is not actually how to validate file size and extension but how to return validation errors with another validation errors. I have two points.

## Point 1

```
app = FastAPI()


class FileExtensionValidator:
    message = 'Extension “{extension}” not allowed. Allowed extensions are {allowed_extensions}'

    def __init__(self, allowed_extensions=None, message=None):
        if allowed_extensions is not None:
            allowed_extensions = [allowed_extension.lower() for allowed_extension in allowed_extensions]
        self.allowed_extensions = allowed_extensions
        if message is not None:
            self.message = message

    def __call__(self, file: UploadFile):
        extension = Path(file.filename).suffix[1:].lower()
        if self.allowed_extensions is not None and extension not in self.allowed_extensions:
            detail = self.message.format(extension=extension, allowed_extensions=', '.join(self.allowed_extensions))
            raise HTTPException(400, detail=detail)


class MaxFileSizeMBValidator:
    def __init__(self, max_mb: int):
        self.max_mb = max_mb

    def __call__(self, file: UploadFile):
        if file.size / 1024 / 1024 > self.max_mb:
            message = f'Maximum file size exceeded'
            raise HTTPException(400, detail=message)


@router.post(
    '/upload/',
    dependencies=[
        Depends(MaxFileSizeMBValidator(max_mb=1)),
        Depends(FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['.docx'])),
    ]
)
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile, user_id: int = Form()):
    return {'filename': file.filename}
```

This is not working as expected because it does not returns ALL validation errors. F.e. if I pass file `.csv` and without required `user_id` then I get response from FastAPI:

```
{
    "detail": "Extension “csv” not allowed. Allowed extensions are .docx"
}
```

However I'd like to get response both with `user_id` validation error:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "file"
            ],
            "msg": "Extension “csv” not allowed. Allowed extensions are .docx",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        },
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "user_id"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to get response like this? How validation should happen with depends approach if it is possible? I'd like to keep validators separated and use each if needed (some sort of constructor).

## Point 2.

During research of FastAPI source code I found this https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/f7e3559bd5997f831fb9b02bef9c767a50facbc3/fastapi/datastructures.py#L21.

If override UploadFile class:

```
class CustomUploadFile(UploadFile):
    validators = [
        MaxFileSizeMBValidator(max_mb=10),
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['.docx']),
    ]

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls: Type["UploadFile"]) -> Iterable[Callable[..., Any]]:
        yield cls.validate
        
        for validator in cls.validators:
            yield validator
```

it work but is not customizable. Further I had to subclass every time if validators are different.